# Revealing mailto links after Google Analytics trackable click

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mailto

Via Google Analytics (GA), I would like to track how much interest there is in contact e-mail addresses published in user-submitted listings on a (WordPress) website. Just tracking "mailto:" clicks via GA doesn't work, because most people copy and paste an e-mail address, and don't click on it.

So, to track interest, I would like to have e-mail addresses in these user-submitted (and user editable) listings automatically hidden with a clickable overlay ("Click to show e-mail address"), which is trackable in GA, and reveals the e-mail address.

The e-mail addresses are not in their own `<div>`, but are in a `<div>` combined with other user submitted text (about how to contact them), so the selector (if that's the right term) can't be `<div>`--otherwise, would JavaScript along the lines of this work (this is beyond my coding abilities, but was suggested to me)?

```
  $(this).addClass("active")
  << SOME GOOGLE TRACKING CODE HERE >>
});

.email_container a {display: none;}
.email_container.active a {display: block;}
.email_container.active span {display: none;}

<div class="email_container">
  <span>Click to show e-mail address</span>
  <a href="mailto:user@emailaddress.com">user@emailaddress.com</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make something like this work via JavaScript, using the equivalent of the CSS selector `a[href^="mailto:"]`? If so, how so?

EDIT: expanded context--the e-mail addresses are within a `<div>` with other user-submitted and post-submission editable content, like this:

```
<div id="listing_contact" class="listing-contact-wrap">
<h3 id="label-listing_contact" class="custom-label" >How to Contact:</h3> 

<p>You can contact us at <a href="mailto:user@emailaddress.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">user@emailaddress.com</a> or fax to: 555-555-5555.</p>

</div>
```

I can manually insert a class into the `<a href="mailto:">` in question, if helpful.

Comment: "Most people copy and paste an e-mail address, and don't click on it" - do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [click event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the span then add a class to the `mailto` link when it's clicked.

This allows you to track the clicks on the `span` in GA.

I used the same HTML you have in your question but I would recommend adding unique classes if possible.

```js
const showEmail = document.querySelector('.email_container span')
const mailTo = document.querySelector('.email_container a')

showEmail.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mailTo.classList.add('visible')
});
```

```css
.email_container a {
  display: none;
}

.email_container a.visible {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="email_container">
  <span>Click to show e-mail address</span>
  <a href="mailto:user@emailaddress.com">user@emailaddress.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! So, is there a way to do this through targeting the a[href^="mailto:"] specifically, instead of the <div>? 

To provide context, the e-mail addresses are within a <div> with other, user-submitted and editable content (edited original question to expand).